# What are the security concerns of using a unique URL for authentication

Tags: url, architecture, system-design

What are the security concerns of using a unique URL to authenticate/authorize a user as Google Docs does when sharing is set to "everyone with the link can view/edit"?

Assuming these URLs are not cached on search engines and the user who generated the record only shares the URL with those they are comfortable with, are there any other glaring security issues that need to be considered?

Comment: Arent't the two you listed glaring enough?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I clarified. In addition to those mentioned.

Comment: My question still stands. Aren't the two you've already listed glaring enough? Note that enterprises using Google suite can further limit the audience of such a link to only valid enterprise users in the same company.